# react how to properly set the state (with redux)

Tags: reactjs

```
import React from 'react'
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import {getSpecificMod } from '../../actions/mods'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

const DownloadFiles = ({ currMod, getSpecificMod, getModFiles }) => {
    const title = window.location.pathname.split('/')[4]
    const [mod, setMod] = useState({})

    useEffect(() => {
        getModFiles(title)
        setMod(currMod[0])
    }, []) // without the brackets the server gets infinite requests but atleast the state gets updated...

    return (
        currMod && mod !== undefined
        ?
        <div class="container">
            <h1>{mod.title} {mod.id}</h1>
        </div>
        :
        null
    )
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    currMod: state.mods.currMod,
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {getSpecificMod})(DownloadFiles)
```

Whatever I do, I cannot ever properly update the state without refreshing the page or sending infinite request to the server... both are horrible practices but for some reason I cannot find a good solution, here I have a component where a function gets executed via redux which retrieves a mod from the server, in the redux devtools the mod is clearly there, but the state always remains empty, what can I do?

**redux state**

```
'mod' : {'title': 'A Mod', 'id': 1}
```

Comment: "without the brackets the server gets infinite requests but atleast the state gets updated" - This is because of how `useEffect`'s dependency array works. If you do not pass it an array, it will run on every render (essentially the same as if you hadn't put the `useEffect` there in the first place). When you give it an empty array, you're telling it "I have no dependencies that you should update for". If you need it to update when a variable changes you should indicate that with `useEffect(() => { /* ... */ }, [variableToUpdateOn])`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I am not sure why you have this line.

```
 const [mod, setMod] = useState({})
```

Actually, `mod` is decided as `currMod[0]`. In other words, it can be calculated from `props` and it is anti pattern to use `state` that can be calculated from `props`.

Second, the problem is that you pass `[]` as a second parameter of `useEffect`. This means you are going to excute the content after component is mounted. (Not whenever component is re-rendered)  You can update it as follow.

```
useEffect(() => {
        getModFiles(title)
        setMod(currMod[0])
    }, [currMod])
```